# Trying to write a simple Joomla plugin

Tags: database, joomla, joomla2.5, updating

Please help, this is my first plugin I'm writing and I'm completely lost. I'm trying to write and update information in a table in a joomla database using my custom **giveBadge()** function. The functions receives two different variables, the first variable is the **$userID** and the second one is the digit **300** which I pass at the bottom of the class using **giveBadge(300)**. At the same comparing the **$userID** in the Joomla database to ensure that the number **300** is given to the current user logged in the Joomla site.

Thanks in advance.

```
<?php


     defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;


      class plgUserBadge extends JPlugin
      {
           public function onUserLogin () {
                $user =& JFactory::getUser();
                $userID =& user->userID;

                return $userID;
           }

           public function giveBadge ($userID, &$badgeID) {
                // Get a db connection.
                $db = JFactory::getDbo();

                // Create a new query object.
                $query = $db->getQuery(true);

                // Fields to update.
                $fields = array(
                    'profile_value=\'Updating custom message for user 1001.\'',
                    'ordering=2');

                // Conditions for which records should be updated.
                $conditions = array(
                    'user_id='.$userID, 
                    'profile_key=\'custom.message\'');

                $query->update($db->quoteName('#__user_badges'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

                $db->setQuery($query);

                try {
                    $result = $db->query(); 
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    // Catch the error.
                }es = array(1001, $db->quote('custom.message'), $db->quote('Inserting a record using insert()'), 1);

            }   

        }

     giveBadge(300);  //attaches to $badgeID    

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is not going well with your code:

- You can **drop the assign by reference** in all your code (&) - you really don't need it, in 99% of the cases.
- **Use an IDE** (for example Eclipse with PDT). At the top of your code you have `& user->userID;` Any IDE will spot your error and also other things in your code.
- Study existing plugins to understand how they work. Here is also the [documentation on plugins](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User#onUserLogin).
- **The method onUserLogin() will automatically be called by Joomla** when the specific event is triggered (when your plugin is activated). Check with a `die("My plugin was called")` to see if your plugin is really called
- **inside onUserLogin() you do all your business logic.** You are not supposed to return something, just return true. Right now your method does absolutely nothing. But you can call $this->giveBadge() to move the logic to another method.

Comment: When I see such a question (new user) and answer, with 0 - 0 upvotes I always ask myself a question. Why new user ask, and dont even care to say thanks? +1, Best regards :).